# Printed Circuit Board Layout

Tags: pcb, cmos

[image]

I am working on a printed circuit board layout.  I understand the circuitry within the red box, however, I am having trouble deciphering the purpose of the purple lines and why the bottom-most contacts are both connected to ground.  My goal is to be able to create a transistor schematic out of the layout.

Comment: We have trouble deciphering the purpose of any colour or letters there, where is that even from? If it is a program screenshot then look up the docs or layer view which should name every layer

Comment: Schematic and net labels please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That isn't a circuit board, it's a diagram of (part of) a chip. The various colors represent different steps used in the fabrication of the chip, such as ion implantation and the deposition of oxide, polysilicon and metal layers.

What you have there is the basic [6-transistor SRAM cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory#Design). In addition to the power and ground connections, you have two bit lines — the purple lines that run all the way from top to bottom — and a "word select line" — the red line that runs horizontally near the bottom.

Wherever red (probably polysilicon) crosses a green or orange area marked with little triangles (N or P type implant to form channels), a transistor is formed.